# JSTree Types plugin not working with Rel attribute

Tags: jstree

Here is how i configure the jsTree Plugin:

```
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#FoldersTreeContainer").jstree({
            "core": {
                "animation": 150
            },

            "themes": {
                "rtl": true,
                "theme": "classic",
                "dots": false,
                "icons": true
            },

            "types": {
                "types": {
                    "Normal": {
                        "icon": { "image": "\Content\css\jsTree\default\Folder.png" },
                    },

                    "Legend": {
                        "icon": { "image": "\Content\css\jsTree\default\Legend.png" },
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["html_data", "themes", "types"]
        });
    });
```

now here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="FoldersTreeContainer">
  <ul id="FoldersTree">
    <li rel="Normal"><a href="#" >other</a></li>
    <li rel="Normal"><a href="#" >item1</a></li>
    <li rel="Normal"><a href="" >item2</a></li>
    <li rel="Legend"><a href="#" >item3-legend</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I use the "rel" attribute of the `<li>` tag for the type but i still get the default folder icons..

what am i dooing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the **3.x** version of jstree which does not take the rel attribute into account. If you are using the 3.x version, more information can be found at this link : https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/473